# Getting 32-bit grub to automatically boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

After so, so much pain and a lot of time (this is too common a prelude), I've managed to get Ubuntu 15.10 installed on the infamous Asus X205TA. It is currently set up in the following way:

- `/dev/mmcblk0p1` is the fat32 bootloader
- `/dev/mmcblk0p2` is the ext4 OS
- `/dev/mmcblk0p3` is swap

Now I managed to hack-and-slash my way through a bunch of guides and eventually get a 32-bit grub (2.02 beta, as it were) installed onto the boot partition in a way that boots up the grub command prompt. I can then boot by entering the following commands [and typing veeery carefully due to the oversensitivity of the keyboard at this stage]:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,gpt2)
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-16-generic root=/dev/mmcblk0p2
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-16-generic
grub> boot
```

This boots just fine into Ubuntu.

**The question is, how can I make this automated (or kick me into the grub menu with the countdown ...)?**

---

I also attempted to use Boot Repair, which did some magic but ultimately did not fix the problem. However, it did seem to mount appropriately and persistently the `/dev/mmcblk0p1` to `/boot/grub`. I believe this, in combination of the accepted answer terminal commands, were the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, typing `sudo update-grub` should do the task if your GRUB is based on Ubuntu's GRUB. If not, `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` should do it.

Alternatively, ***IF*** your installation is of a 32-bit Ubuntu, you might find it easier to install my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) You can install the PPA and it should set everything up automatically to boot *without* GRUB. This will work only on a same-bit-depth basis, though -- that is, if you've installed a 32-bit Ubuntu on a 32-bit EFI (or more commonly, a 64-bit Ubuntu on a 64-bit EFI). If you've installed a 64-bit Ubuntu on a 32-bit EFI, you'll still need GRUB to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

I have the x205ta too. I originally used [Lopaka's guide](https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-14.10-install-asus-x205ta.md) which has since been updated and not tested by me.

You may have also seen KemyLand's guide on [this Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254322&page=34). This uses a `chroot` method, but if you boot from GRUB the commands to do after the `chroot` might fix your problem. Maybe you just need the packages  `efibootmgr`, `grub-efi-ia32`, and `grub-efi-ia32-bin` (you probably already have them) and these two lines

```
sudo grub-install --target=i386-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=grub_uefi --recheck
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Recently I installed 16.04 with the automated installer after making a usb to live boot to test it out. Just for fun, I let it attempt to reboot
And I could hardly believe my eyes when it booted! So apparently compiling or even tweaking GRUB for 32-bit UEFI is no longer needed in 16.04 for this device. Happy days if you feel like moving to 16.04...

Comment: Indeed I saw that guide, and I attempted those directions but ran into an issue during make that said my m*.sh (can't recall which file, modprobe maybe?) was not valid. I looked around for solutions to *that* problem to no avail, so I eventually gave up. 16.04 may be the way to go ...